# Servicemix/Camel : how to leverage OSGI to create "pluggable" bundles?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Scenario : I'll try to put an analogy with the loan broker example from the EIP book

1. The customer sends a quote request
2. (The loan broker requests customer credit score from the credit bureau)
3. The loan broker sends quote requests to each bank.

The problem

- In my case point 1 and 2 are in the same camel context (or osgi bundle)
- Each bank has a separate bundle, exposing endpoints to the loan-broker-bundle through NMR
- loan-broker-bundle doesn't know about the banks beforehand since we keep partnering with new banks every now and then

What I did

- Created a registry class and a bankDescriptor interface in loan-broker-bundle
- each bank bundle when started calls the registery to add its bankDescriptor (spring init) that tells the loan broker what endpoint to call to get a quote.
- loan-broker-bundle main route uses recipientList (a processor sets target endpoints by asking the registery) to route quote requests

The question

Hoping my description was clear enough, you can see that this is a really simple implementation. What are its limits ? How can i turn this registery into an osgi service ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I developed a solution like this based on SpringDM for a client. There's a full write up of how to do this at http://www.jakubkorab.net/2012/05/system-integrations-as-plugins-using-camel-and-servicemix.html with full source code available at https://github.com/FuseByExample/smx-application-plugins

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

In OSGi there is a great registry at your disposal: The OSGi service registry. So my proposal is to do this slightly differently. Define a service interface for the quote requests and store it in a api bundle. Then let each bank implement this interface and publish the implementation as an OSGi service.

The loan broker bundle can then list all OSGi services in the OSGi service registry and call each to get the quote. In blueprint there is a nice tag  that you can use to inject the list into a bean property of List. Spring DM perhaps has something similar.

Camel currently does not have way to call all OSGi services of a type. We discussed a new osgi service compomnent that would be able to do this. So probably we will soon have a solution.

Comment: Great news, that would be a welcome addition. Thank you for the answer!